# EF retrieve all records without use where clauses

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In this case :

```
var user = (from user in appContext.User
               where user.username == Username
               where user.enabled).FirstOrDefault();
```

The SQL Query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM User
```

EF retrieve all records and make after the where query. Why?

How to get only the entities corresponding to my where clauses?

Note : appContext.User is an ICollection

Comment: Can you correct your question. It is unclear what do you mean

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the query syntax you are using is just syntax-sugar. It gets converted into the following code:

```
appContext.User.Where(user => user.username== UserName).Where(user => user.isenabled);
```

`appContext.User` being an `ICollection` at compile-time is the problem. The `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` linq methods are extension methods. That means that whether the `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` version of the method is called is determined at compile-time (**not** at run-time).

Even if `appContext.User` is an `IQueryable` at run-time, it doesn't matter, since it's declared as an `ICollection` at compile-time (which impelments `IEnumerable`), the `IEnumerable` extension method will be called. Those extension methods take in a `Func<>` which means your lambda expression will be compiled into a method.

On the other hand, if `appContext.User` were an `IQueryable` at compile-time, the `IQueryable` extension methods would be use, and therefore your lambda expression would be converted into an expression tree, and therefore, could be evaluated at run-time by Entity Framework.

On a side note, Laurent, I want to give you credit for "looking under the hood" and noticing that the query isn't what you expect. Too many developers just assume everything is working as they expect and are then puzzled why they run into performance issues down the road.

Comment: Ok but it's the classes generated by my edmx... why they use ICollection if ICollection doesn't implement IQueryable ?

Comment: If `appContext` is your DataContext, then I would expect User to be `IQueryable`. If it really is declared as `ICollection`, then it may be a configuration issue you have with EF. There are settings in the .edmx file that affect the generated code. Worst case scenario, if it is an `IQueryable` at runtime, you can call `AsQueryable()` on your `Users` property, and then do your filtering. I would double check the generated query to make sure that works.

Answer (score 0):

If appContext.User is an IQueryable, then that query will not produce a `select *` type query.

If you did something like `appContext.User.ToList().Where(user => user.username == Username)` then the query would return all records are you're telling and `IQueryable` to materialise all the records into objects (via a `.ToList()`) before applying the filter.

Can you run a profiler on the database and add in the actual output?

Comment: No it's an ICollection<User>

Comment: @Laurent Then that means you've already pulled it into memory; it is not a representation of a potential database query.

Comment: If it's an iCollection<User> that would suggest that you're accessing a navigation property from another type (or have located 'one' of of the collections from another type).

If you track down the Model.Context.cs I expect Users will be defined at a DbSet.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var user = (from user in appContext.Set<User>()
            where user.username == Username
            where user.enabled).FirstOrDefault();
```